# JavaScript OnPageLoad debugging without debug command

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, onload, breakpoints

I need to start debug JavaScript when page has loaded and Javascript starts.(OnLoad event call), but i haven't acess to source code of web site and can't modified it(like debug; command).
help please with it
best regards
Vlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using some Web Browser tool? Like Firebug on Mozilla or  Developer Tools in Chrome(Just click F12 while in Chrome Browser, Select Sources Tab and then select the .js file you want.)

I guess the onload event will be triggered with something like

```
<body onload="load()">
```

So stick a breakpoint on the load() method.

Comment: I can't make a breakpoint becouse i need to start debuging when JavaScript begin run, immediately after html retrieving, i do not have time to make this.

Comment: ** I found the solution in the next way: i put the breakpoint after the hypertext has been loaded and then refresh the page, if hypertext was cached then breakpoints run debug mode in chrome